# Jenkins Job Builder - Automatic Pipeline Job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-builder

Currently, in Jenkins Job Builder, I can specify downstream jobs through the **publishers** option like this:

```
- job-template:
    name: foo-one
    project-type: freestyle
    disabled: false
    ...
    publishers:
      - pipeline:
          project: foo-two
```

When the **foo-one** job is created, the downstream connection exists within Jenkins but the Build other projects entry is **'Build other projects (Manual Step)'**.  How do I indicate through Jenkins Job Builder that the downstream connection to job **foo-two** needs to be automated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could not figure out how to resolve the issue using Jenkins Job Builder publisher/pipeline tag.  So, ended up:

1. Configuring the **foo-one** job within Jenkins to kick off **foo-two** when **foo-one** completed successfully
2. Retrieve the **foo-one** job's config.xml file through: **curl -O http://localhost:8080/job/foo-one/config.xml**
3. Extracted the relevant XML from the config.xml file that controlled the downstream kickoff logic.
4. Using the Jenkins Job Builder **xml** and **publisher** tags:

   ```
   - job-template:
       name: foo-one
       project-type: freestyle
       disabled: false
       ...
       publishers:
         - raw:
             xml: |
               <hudson.tasks.BuildTrigger>
                 <childProjects>foo-two</childProjects>
                 <threshold>
                   <name>SUCCESS</name>
                   <ordinal>0</ordinal>
                   <completeBuild>true</completeBuild>
                 </threshold>
               </hudson.tasks.BuildTrigger>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `trigger-parameterized-builds` for triggering downstream jobs.

```
- job-template:
    name: foo-one
    project-type: freestyle
    disabled: false
    ...

    publishers:
      - trigger-parameterized-builds:
          - project: 'foo-two'
            condition: UNSTABLE_OR_BETTER
            fail-on-missing: true
```